# bad X server connection -" windows 10 + wsl"

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, point-cloud-library

I get the following error when I try to run a [tutorial code](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/matrix_transform.php#matrix-transform) with vs code on a wsl. I mean,i am using vs code on windows 10 but my all builds system are on wsl ubuntu. To explain it briefly, I want to display 3d image on the screen.

```
ERROR: In /build/vtk6-VHOYAG/vtk6-6.3.0+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1475
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x7fffca1a12a0): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm not familiar with linux systems but i think, i need a permission to rendering. Do you know how to display the images?

Comment: If you have a new problem, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry, i fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: If you want to run a graphical program on wls you need an X server that runs on Windows 10. You can use Xming to get outputs from wsl [2](https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2018/01/30/hands-on-with-wsl-graphical-apps.aspx).